# Calling __construct from child class statically(?)

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

I have the following php code:

```
<?php

class ParentClass {

    public $table_name;

    function __construct() {
        $this->table_name = strtolower(__CLASS__);
    }

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        //And I also want to put here other codes
    }

}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = new ChildClass();

echo $parent->table_name . "<br />" . $child->table_name;

?>
```

the result is

```
parentclass
parentclass
```

however I want it to be

```
parentclass
childclass
```

How do I achieve it?
Late static binding would solve my problem, however it cant be called statically of course.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: can I know what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes, please reread my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in PHP5.5 and upwards:

```
class ParentClass 
{
    public $table_name;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->table_name = strtolower(static::class);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();     
        // ...
    }
}

$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = new ChildClass();

echo $parent->table_name . "<br />" . $child->table_name;
```

For reference, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class.

Answer (score 1):

Use `static::class` to get the name of the class using late static binding:

```
class ParentClass {

    public $table_name;

    function __construct() {
        $this->table_name = strtolower(static::class);
    }

}
```

This will result in the desired

```
parentclass
childclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class ParentClass {

    public $table_name;

function __construct() {
    $this->table_name = strtolower(__CLASS__);
}

}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->table_name = strtolower(__CLASS__);
    //And I also want to put here other codes
}

}
```

$parent = new ParentClass();
$child = new ChildClass();

echo $parent->table_name . "
" . $child->table_name;

?>